# XPATH expression to get the XML file name

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible to get the name of the xml file which is processed using xpath expression?

Comment: Are you using an xslt processor?

Answer (score 2):

No. The file name is not part of the document. You can also process a document that does not originate in a file at all.

Answer (score 2):

Not in XPath 1.0.

**In XPath 2.0 use**:

```
document-uri(/)
```

**The argument to `document-uri()` must be a document node**. If anything else (like `/html`) is specified for the argument, the result, as per the **[W3C F&O Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-document-uri)** is the empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In xpath 2 you can use document-uri

E.g.

```
 document-uri(/html)
```